# Is Windows Server 2008 R2 arp cache per user or per machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, arp

When running `arp -a` in a Windows Server 2008 R2 prompt, will the returned entries cover connections from all users logged on to the machine or only the current?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The arp cache is a table containing all the arp entries the machine knows about.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786759%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)  It's not collected or segmented in a user-specific fashion.

Be aware, however, that dynamic arp entries expire fairly quickly, so your arp table might not even be a good representation of MAC addresses the computer has collected, just a good representation of the past couple of minutes' worth of network activity.  (From the link above):

> Dynamic ARP cache entries
>
> These entries are added and deleted automatically during normal use of TCP/IP sessions with remote computers. Dynamic entries age and expire from the cache if not reused within 2 minutes.

Comment: AFAIR default expire time is 30+-15 seconds since Vista/2008

Comment: @dusan.bajic  Could be.  Could also be the rest of the text at that link - `If a dynamic entry is reused within 2 minutes, it may remain in the cache and age up to a maximum cache life of 10 minutes before being removed or requiring cache renewal by using the ARP broadcast process.`  Not something I really have much motivation to research, you know?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the ARP table is part of the TCP/IP stack, thus it's machine wide.